# sreg Yahoo problems

Tags: yahoo, registration, dotnetopenauth

May you please look at the issue:

You may test Yahoo sreg at
"https://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx"

ID : "https://me.yahoo.com/"
username: goughev@yahoo.com
password: paranoid

Now the problem

This code work with Google but not with Yahoo sreg,
becase response.GetUntrustedExtension() alwase returns null values for properties for Yahoo

```
        var opUrl = LoginCore.GetProviderUrl(provider, openId);
        var openIdRelyingParty = new OpenIdRelyingParty(null);
        var response = openIdRelyingParty.GetResponse();
        Identifier id;

        if (response == null)
        {
            if (Identifier.TryParse(opUrl, out id))
            {
                try
                {
                    var claim = new ClaimsRequest();
                    claim.Email = DemandLevel.Require;
                    claim.FullName = DemandLevel.Request;
                    claim.Gender = DemandLevel.Request;
                    claim.Nickname = DemandLevel.Require;
                    var request = openIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(opUrl);

                    request.AddExtension(claim);
                    return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Model.Errors.Add(GeneralErrors.Unexpected());
                return View("SignupUnTrustedOpenId");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                   var claimsData = response.GetUntrustedExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
                    if (claimsData != null)
                    {
                        email = claimsData.Email;
```

I am using folowing configuration:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid>
        <relyingParty>
            <security requireSsl="false" ignoreUnsignedExtensions="false" maximumHashBitLength="256" minimumHashBitLength="160" rejectDelegatingIdentifiers="true" rejectUnsolicitedAssertions="false" requireAssociation="false" requireDirectedIdentity="false" />
            <behaviors>
                <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
            </behaviors>
        </relyingParty>
    </openid>
    <messaging>
        <untrustedWebRequest>
            <whitelistHosts>
                <add name="localhost" />
            </whitelistHosts>
        </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```

I am using the latiest version 3.2.0.9177

Thank you very much for help

Vitaly

Comment: I have no idea bout donetopenid, but if the problem is related to OpenID itself, it would be helpful if you posted final OpenID response.

Comment: Could some one mask the password please?

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo's SREG extension support is currently only in beta.  Yahoo is only willing to expose SREG support to whitelisted RPs.  [See here.](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2008/11/yahoo_openid_test.html)

I went through the test-id.org test with my own Yahoo account and it worked.  Your code to adding the sreg extension looks fine.  So I suspect the only problem is that you're not on Yahoo's whitelist yet.