# How to make dotnetopenid work with AOL

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, aol

The library does not work with AOL (Google and Yahoo are OK). AOL uses openid version 1.0 and I think it is due to this. I have tried extremeswank - works with AOL - no problems, and sreg works with AOL too.

I am using the latiest version 3.2.0.9177 of dotnetopenid.

You may check code and configuration at '[sreg Yahoo problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311607/sreg-yahoo-problems)'

May you please check support for version OpenID 1.0 ?

Thank you Bye

Vitaly

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: AOL does only support OpenID 1.1 currently.

DotNetOpenAuth fully supports OpenID 1.1 RPs and OPs.  AOL included.  I just tried [the DotNetOpenAuth demo RP](http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.2/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/) and logged in successfully with my http://openid.aol.com/webmyway OpenID.

If it still doesn't work for you, can you please include repro steps that demonstrate the broken behavior, and explain what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.2/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/
with your ID: "http://openid.aol.com/webmyway"

It reports Login failed: No OpenID endpoint found.

Thank you
Bye

Vitaly

Comment: A comment on my answer is the more appropriate medium on StackOverflow to respond to my answer.  Anyway, try it again (twice).  I'm sure the error you saw was due to a timeout because either the sample app or AOL needed to warm up.  If you try a second time in a row, the gears will be greased and it should work.